# ClassNotFoundException/NoClassDefFoundError using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, ldap, cxf

I am testing a web services using CXF 2.7.14 over Tomcat 7 on Eclipse Kepler EE. The web service is invoked by incoming request; however, before it gets to do any processing it's getting ClassNotFoundException: netscape.ldap.LDAPException (as well as NoClassDefFoundError).  Strange thing is, if I run the main() in lieu of CXF invocation, I would not get the Exceptions.  Anyone has any idea?

Here's the stack trace:

```
Mar 12, 2015 3:15:23 PM org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain doDefaultLogging
WARNING: Application {http://g.a.com}MyService#{http://g.a.com/myservice}getAddr has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: netscape/ldap/LDAPException
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.createFault(AbstractInvoker.java:170)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.createFault(AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.java:272)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:136)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.java:237)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(JAXWSMethodInvoker.java:69)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:75)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:249)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:248)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:222)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:153)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:171)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:286)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:206)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: netscape/ldap/LDAPException
    at com.a.g.myservice.MyTypeImpl.getAddr(MyTypeImpl.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:188)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:104)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: netscape.ldap.LDAPException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    ... 44 more
```

UPDATE: I started commented things out and eventually found the culprit yet I do not know the cause:  **As soon as** I include the "catch" statement shown below, I get the Exceptions.

```
import netscape.ldap.LDAPConnection;
import netscape.ldap.LDAPException;
...
    try {
    ...
    } catch (LDAPException le) {
    ...
```

If I include the full path, netscape.ldap.LDAPException, same Exception. This Netscape package was part of the a JAR file which I added as external JAR in the project Build Path, as shown in the .classpath file excerpt here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="C:/Users/dh931w/g2src/jars/ldapjdk418.jar"/>
```

No problem at compile time. Any idea why I get these exceptions at runtime?

Comment: I added an ldap jdk in the external jar list. Is it possible it is conflicting with something built-in Apache AXIS or CXF?

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse, when you run main() via Run As... Java Application, it is using a different JRE than had you Run As...Run on Server.  So specifying the External Jars in the project's Build Path is good only as far as compiling and Running As Java Application.  When you Run on Server, you must do the equivalent to the server you specify (e.g. Tomcast). Too bad Eclipse doesn't do this for you.

There are at least two ways to do this:

1. From Run As... Run Configurations, select Tomcat and add all the External Jars to the User Entries in the Classpath tab the same way you would for the project's Build Path.
2. Copy all of your External Jars to the jre/lib/ext folder of the installed JRE that you designate.

I think you can also use manifest files to locate all the external jar files but I've never done that. Also, under Windows | Preferences | Server| Runtime Environments | Default Classpath Entries, you can add the entire folder containing your external jar files.